# Can't run appclip from XCode

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

I'm building an app with an AppClip. Since last week, I can't run the AppClip target on neither physical device nor simulator. There is no error anywhere (as far as I can tell) - only, the AppClip wouldn't appear on screen (XCode insists the target got installed and is running).

Oddly enough, when I archive the project and upload it to App Store Connect, I can run the AppClip from TestFlight just fine.

It's possible that the issue is there since I updated XCode and iPhone to the latest versions but I'm not 100% about that as I worked on the "main app" at the moment and only got back to AppClip a couple of days after the update.

Of course - I tried to restart, disconnect, connect everything.

Anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching your App Clip with _XCAppClipURL scheme variable? There's more info in this WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10146/